# Insert and Update XML with DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm saving game data on a XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<games>
  <player id="1">
    <name>Player 1</name>
    <level>2</level>
    <score>1000</score>
  </player>
  <player id="2">
    <name>Player 2</name>
    <level>4</level>
    <score>7500</score>
  </player>
</games>
```

How I can insert a new player node at the end of the xml and then update the xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Element player = document.createElement("player");
player.setAttribute("id","3");

Element name = document.createElement("name");
name.setTextContent("Player 3");
player.appendChild(name);

Element level = document.createElement("level");
level.setTextContent("4");
player.appendChild(level);

Element score = document.createElement("score");
score.setTextContent("10000");
player.appendChild(score);

Element games = document.findElementsByTag("games").item(0);
games.appendChild(player);
```